# Can I make a Body immune to Gravity?

Tags: android, andengine, gravity

I want a PhysicsWorld where only some elements are affected by gravity (as set by the Accelerometer). I've tried setting the mass of some objects to 0, but this doesn't work. Is there any way of making some Bodys immune to the gravity of the world they're in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about how you'd do it in the real world - you need an upwards force to counteract gravity to make something neutrally buoyant.

So try applying an acceleration to the body which is equal and opposite to your gravitational acceleration.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but that actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I made some alterations to the Box2D extension to include the setGravityScale method from the more recent version of Box2D. I posted the link at,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239548/how-do-i-make-a-body-ignore-gravity-andengine/12770735#12770735

e.g., to make a body ignore gravity call,
Body.setGravityScale(0.0f);

I included an explanation of how it was implemented. There is also a download provided for GLES1.

Hope this helps.